# "to point to / towards / in / into"

Tags: difference

"To point at", "to point to" and "to point towards" are frequent phrases in dictionaries with the verb "point".

But there are also two other phrases: "to point in" and "to point into".
I'd like to find out when we can use them:
When can we use "to point in"?
When can we use "to point into"?

"To point at" — I think I kind of understand it.
But I can't understand what is the difference between the other phrases.
To figure it out, I prepared some examples:

[ahdictionary.com](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=into):
**(1)**  *pointed **into** the sky*
my variants:
**(1a)**  *pointed **to** the sky*
**(1b)**  *pointed **towards** the sky*
**(1c)**  *pointed **in** the sky*
What is the difference between (1), (1a), (1b) and (1c)?

[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/point):
**(2)** *She pointed **in** the direction of the car park*.
my variants:
**(2a)** *She pointed **to** the direction of the car park*.
**(2b)** *She pointed **towards** the direction of the car park*.
**(2c)** *She pointed **into** the direction of the car park*.
What is the difference between (2), (2a), (2b) and (2c)?

Comment: It's a bit weird to *point towards **the direction of** X*, and *pointing **into** the direction of X* is completely non-idiomatic. If you can ***see*** X, you just *point **to** X* or ***...at** X*. If you ***can't*** see it, you either *point **towards** X* or *point **in the direction of** X*.

Comment: ... you can only *point **into** X* if X is some kind of container / enclosed space, OR something "amorphous" or "abstract", such as *pointing into the darkness*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you say "to point into X" where X is some kind of container or enclosed space. Could you give me please some examples so that I will understand what you mean?

Comment: pointed into is wrong here. All these are different questions.

Comment: Have a look at Google Books matches for [***He pointed into the...***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+pointed+into+the%22) Actual "containers" on the first page there include ***hole, bathroom, tunnel,*** and ***cylindrical object***. Plus  "amorphous" or "abstract" referents such as ***distance*** and ***dark***. Plus there's ***He pointed into the valley*** and ***...into the water***, where the specific choice of ***into*** rather than ***to*** or ***at*** tells us he's interested in something ***inside*** the valley, the water, or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really a phrase *point in.* In your sentence 2, the phrase is *in the direction of* which means the same as *towards*, so 2b should be **She pointed towards the car park.** 2a doesn't really mean anything. I see that the American Heritage Dictionary also defines that sense of *into* as *in the direction of*, so **She pointed into the car park** would probably mean that she was standing near the boundary of the car park and pointing towards the middle of it.

Comment: Can we use the verb "_point to_" instead of "_point towards_"? For example: "_She pointed **to** the car park_" instead of "_She pointed **towards** the car park_." Thanks.

Comment: You point **to** something to identify it. _"I've left my car there" she said, pointing to the car park._ You point **towards** something to indicate direction. _"He went that way" she said, pointing towards the car park._